# Where can I find the booklet "Structure of Debate"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, chinuch-education, adult-learning, jewish-books

I was in a different shul this past Shabbos when I saw a very interesting booklet of more than 200 pages called "Structure of Debate" by Jonathan Bailey. It's a primer to learning gemara. I tried locating the book online but I cannot find any mention of it at all. I would much appreciate if someone can point out where I can download a copy or purchase this book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rabbi Jonathan Bailey can be contacted by e-mail using the mailbox rilbash on the server gmail.com